# CustomAdapter from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to set up a ListView from SQLite database with a CustomAdapter.
I'd like this ListView to change depending on which "moods" is found in database.

Moods basically goes from 0 to 4.
Some advice might be helpful. Thanks a lot guys...

```
     // TODO
    // Replace with SQLite data
    DatabaseHelper myDB = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    List<MoodItem> moodItemList = myDB.getAllMoodItems();

    String[] mMoods = new String[moodItemList.size()];
    for(MoodItem moodItem : moodItemList){
        mMoods[position] = moodItemList.get(position);
        Log.d("Mood :", " " + moodItem.getMood());
    }

// It's working when I use this for mMoods
// int[] mMoods = {0, 3, 4, 2, 1};

        switch (mMoods[position]) {
            case 0:
                // Bad mood here, so red background and the smallest width
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xffde3c50);                     // @color/faded_red
                mCustomView.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getWidth() / 5;        // 1/5 of screen's width
                return mCustomView;
            case 1:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xff9b9b9b);                     // @color/warm_grey
                mCustomView.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getWidth() * 2 / 5;    // 2/5 of screen's width
                return mCustomView;
            case 2:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xa5468ad9);                     // @color/cornflower_blue_65
                mCustomView.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getWidth() * 3 / 5;    // 3/5 of screen's width
                return mCustomView;
            case 3:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xffb8e986);                     // @color/light_sage
                mCustomView.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getWidth() * 4 / 5;    // 4/5 of screen's width
                return mCustomView;
            case 4:
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xfff9ec4f);                     // @color/banana_yellow
                mCustomView.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getWidth();            // screen's width
                return mCustomView;
        }
    return mCustomView;
```

[See this picture as a result for what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMVU6.png)

EDIT: 
Replace String[] with int[]. That's ok for the switch. 
The point is, when I use my code in comments:

```
int[] mMoods = {"0", "3", "4", "2", "1"};
```

The CustomAdapter shows everything I need: red color for 0 and 1/5 of the width. blue color for 3 and 3/5 of the width, etc...

But the real purpose here is to replace the int[] mMoods with real data from SQLite database. And when I use the code for this, my ListView items are all the same everytime... :/

And I can't find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to answer my question:

In View getView() of my CustomAdapter :

Opening Database and my Cursor

`DatabaseHelper myDB = new DatabaseHelper(getContext())
 Cursor mCursor = myDB.getAllData();`

Creating my ArrayList and adding SQLite datas to it

```
ArrayList<Integer> mMoodsArray = new ArrayList<>();
while (mCursor.moveToNext()){
   String mComment = mCursor.getString(2);
   int mMood = mCursor.getInt(3);
   mCommentsArray.add(mComment);
   mMoodsArray.add(mMood);
}
```

Creating my Array from ArrayList

```
int[] mMoods = new int[mMoodsArray.size()];
```

And adding all of this in my Array

```
for ( int i = 0; i < mMoodsArray.size(); i++){
  mMoods[i] = mMoodsArray.get(i);
}
```

And now the switch is working fine and well !

I don't really know if there is a better way to do what I've done. But it works !

I hope this could help somebody else.

Thanks.